# Storing and filtering date field independent of timezone?

Tags: java, web-applications, calendar, timezone

I have a web application which can be accessed across the globe where user can store the comment and filter it based on date when comment was entered.

Say I have a web server and database somewhere in US. 
User from china enter a comment on 7th Oct 2017(but at server/DB date is 6th Oct). So server saves it as 6 Oct
Now user through filter(on UI) want to get the comment entered on 7th October, he won't get any result.

**My approach to solve this problem independent of  server  and end user location**

1. When comment is entered, store the date at server to any one timezone(while storing and filtering) say UTC. So even if server is EST timezone, convert current time in UTC timezone and store it
2. Now when user enters any date on UI for filtering, get the user locale/timezone from HTTP Request and convert the user entered date(considering his timezone) to UTC
   and fetch the result from DB based on UTC date
3. Per mine understanding  this approach is independent of  server  and end user location

**Example :-**

1. China user entered a comment on 7th october at 3 AM which is 6th October(7PM) per UTC time
2. New York user tries to search the comment for 6th October. 6th October(0am to 24 pm) translates to 6th October(5 am) to 7th October(5am). So we need to search the comment
   in DB from 6th October(5 am) to 7th October(5am) ?

**Please let me know if it is correct or if there is some better/simple approach.**

Comment: You could set a website's date and time visible to all users and users should  depend on that time to search or do any significant thing... But it's a good question in my opinion.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by `You could set a website's date and time visible to all users and users should depend on that time to search or do any significant thing..`. Do you mean I should publish to users that i will store the date in UTC timezone and while filtering they should enter the date in UTC only ?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant yes, when they search you could tell them to search depending on the UTC timezone for example.